# How to wrap string array in flexbox column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Hi i need to wrap an array like this [TASK 1, TASK 2, TASK 3].

In HTML i want to display it like that TASK 1, TASK 2... and then with a tooltip the user can see the rest of the tasks.

I need that because i have little space in the col.

The piece of HTML is structured like that

EDIT:

```
 <div class="col-2 border-right-yellow fw-bold">
                          <div class="row body-cells flex-center">
                            <div class="col-8">
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">{{resource.resourcePlanDTO.cognome}}</div>
                                <div class="col">{{resource.resourcePlanDTO.nome}}</div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-4">
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                  {{getTasks(resource)}}
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

getTasks is the method i use to take the string array from  the back-end
I tried to use some flexbox classes but it didn't work :(

[image]

Now the array is displayed like you can see in the image in the column No.Task

Anyone can help? :)

Comment: Need to see more code. Can't really tell what's going on from the HTML snippet you provided.

Comment: Ok i edited the code now there is the whole column... Tell me if you need more code :)